# Soldiers in spaceship travel into the past to stop a religious book from being written

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I watched the movie as a teen. I believe the movie is from 80's.
One of the actors is not Jean Claude Van Damme but is similar to him but in less famous movies.

In the future some soldiers were losing a war. So they get on a spaceship and traveled in time back in the past to find a person that wrote a book to prevent him from writing the book which will became like religious book. And they had explosives around their necks, they were 2 guys and a woman. They managed to remove the explosives. And they made it. But only the woman came back to her time in the future and it wasn't the same. It was some beautiful time and I think she was found by some huge unknown for her ship from the new peaceful time and there she met her kid. And she was in a new unknown world but more beautiful world.

Comment: When did you watch the movie (i.e. when were you a teen)? Was it made in America, Britain, ... ? Can you remember what any of the characters looked like? Any little detail could help somebody to identify it for you!

Comment: Sounds almost like Continuum the TV series.

Comment: @Paulie_D that was my first thought as well, though it doesn't exactly fit. No spaceship, there were more than 3, etc

Comment: It is not continuum. It is old movie like from 80's even possible to be from 70's. I've made some corrections in the describtion.

Comment: If I see the actor I will recognize him. I need a good site for movie actors

Comment: Jean Claude - clod is a lump of soil.

Comment: How is the actor like JCVD? Do they look alike, sound alike, play similar roles, act in similar movies?

Comment: They play in similar movies, karate movies, action movies, sci-fi movies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [Total Reality (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120356/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt)

> David Bradley stars as Lt. Rand, a future soldier facing a death
>   sentence is given a chance for freedom if he leads a group of
>   commandos back to 1998 to prevent a group of rebel fighters from
>   preventing the totalitarian government from ever happening. Bradley
>   also has 40 hours to succeed or his device in his neck will explode,
>   along the way Bradley questions his mission.
>
> ---
>
> Total Reality takes place 200 years in the future, where a
>   self-help/cult movement inspirational book written in the late 1990s
>   has grown into an intergalactic dystopian nightmare. Bradley works for
>   the side of the baddies, stamping out a rebellion, but when his CO
>   blasts a ship full of innocent civilians, he blasts his CO and gets
>   sent to military prison with a death sentence. Thing is though, a
>   couple rebels have flown off in a time traveling ship, headed for
>   Earth 1998, so they can take out the dude who wrote the book and the
>   Senator whom he's in cahoots with. Bradley now has a battle of
>   conscience, because if he doesn't complete his mission and kill these
>   rebels, his head will explode, but if he does, the world he knows will
>   continue to suck.

You can watch the full movie [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbjHwQZHuow)

Comment: OMG, Thanks, pori !! I don't know if I will like this movie now, but I liked it back there. It was the first time that the time travel idea touched me with all of its paradoxes. But now I believe everything happens in now, Like you can have access to everything from 0th time dimension, most of people are in 3rd time dimension and they still recognize only 1 of the time dimensions :) The moment when the time traveler girl came back to her own time, and everything was completely different was with very deeply heavy effect/impact on me.